# Как добавить сущность в Minecraft чтобы я мог в неё вселяться и как добавить анимацию к ней?

Tags: minecraft

Blockbench animations. Можете подсказать пожалуйста, я сделал сущность и как мне добавить её в Minecraft чтобы я мог в неё вселяться и как добавить анимацию к ней по нажатию определённой кнопки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я даже не знаю можно ли это считать вопросом по программированию или оффтопом...